# Link <a> on Slider doesn't work mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

This page here: https://www.ohdela.com/

Has a slider at the top of the webpage. If you use chrome tools or you mobile phone and try to click the buttons in each slide - they do not work (give it a second to load completely). This issue only occurs on smaller screen widths. I cannot figure out why. There is nothing on top of them blocking them from being clicked.

The only thing I can think of is that there is javascript somewhere preventing the default action from taking place. Any ideas as to why would be appreciated!

Thanks for looking!

[image]

Comment: It works fine in FireFox, mobile and desktop, so it may be some problems with chrome only.

Comment: I confirm the issue on Chrome for Android.

Comment: @VasilijAltunin Thanks for looking at that. I will confirm I get the same behavior. I tested the default browser that ships with the S7.